# Wikitude - I got weird output when resume the app

Tags: ios, cordova, wikitude

I'm using wikitude sdk for my augmented reality mobile app project. My prob is I got weird output when resume the app on my mobile phone. I'm using the code sample from here. https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples

[image]

Why? Dear staff wikitude, why it happens? @andreas-schacherbauer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with PhoneGap and iOS 7. There is an updated version of the Wikitude Plugin on [Github](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap) (Fri 31.1.14), which includes a workaround for that. Please update your plugin for your project.